# Слайдеры на весь экран

Tags: javascript, frontend, slider, background, веб-дизайн

Всем привет! Хотелось узнать какие сейчас самые лучшие полноэкранные слайдеры для содержания контента сайта и перемещения по нему. Например как на этом фото (справа посередине отображен элемент управления слайдера). То есть когда секции сайта размещены в слайдах.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Если это не полноценный слайдер, а просто фича, написанная на js то где можно подробно про это прочитать?

Comment: fullPage.js, например.

Comment: Спасибо, то что искал)